# Algorithm to find the best possible available times

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Here is my scenario,

I run a Massage Place which offers various type of massages. Say 30 min Massage, 45 min massage, 1 hour massage, etc. I have 50 rooms, 100 employees and 30 pieces of equipment.When a customer books a massage appointment, the appointment requires 1 room, 1 employee and 1 piece of equipment to be available.

What is a good algorithm to find available resources for 10 guests for a given day

**Resources**:

Room – 50

Staff – 100

Equipment – 30

Business Hours : 9AM - 6PM

Staff Hours: 9AM- 6PM

No of guests: 10

**Services**

5 Guests-  (1 hour massages)

3 Guests - (45mins massages)

2 Guests  - (1 hour massage).

They are coming around the same time. Assume there are no other appointment on that day

What is the best way to get ::

- Top 10 result - Fastest search which meets all conditions gets the top 10 result set.  Top ten is defined by earliest available time.  9 – 11AM is best result set.  9 – 5pm is not that good.
- Exhaustive search (Find all combinations)  - all sets – Every possible combination
- First available met (Only return the first match) – stop after one of the conditions have been met

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: no solution, just an additional idea: add the earnings of each treatment into the algorithm since this is your real goal... 3 short massages may be financially not as good as 2 long ones (or the other way round...). And then this would be a rucksack - problem.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784908/effective-timetabling-algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems the number of employees, rooms, and equipment are irrelevant.  It seems like you only care about which of those is the lowest number.  That is your inventory.  So in your case, inventory = 30.

Next, it sounds like you can service all 10 people at the same time within the first hour of business.  In fact, you can service 30 people at the same time.

So, no algorithm is necessary to figure that out, it's a static solution.  If you take @Mario The Spoon's advice and weight the different duration massages with their corresponding profits, then you can start optimizing when you have more than 30 customers at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to solve a problem for which there are quite specialized software applications.  If your problem is small enough, you could try to do a brute force approach using some looping and backtracking, but as soon as the problem becomes too big, it will take too much time to iterate through all possibilities.

If the problem starts to get big, look for more specialized software.  Things to look for are "constraint based optimization" and "constraint programming".

E.g. the ECLIPSe tool is an open-source constraint programming environment.  You can find some examples on http://eclipseclp.org/examples/index.html.  One nice example you can find there is the SEND+MORE=MONEY problem.  In this problem you have the following equation:

```
    S E N D
+   M O R E
-----------
= M O N E Y
```

Replace every letter by a digit so that the sum is correct.
This also illustrates that although you can solve this brute-force, there are more intelligent ways to solve this (see http://eclipseclp.org/examples/sendmore.pl.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea to find a solution:

You might want to try to solve it with a constraint satisfaction problem (CSP) algorithm. That's what some people do if they have to solve timetable problems in general (e.g. room reservation at the University).

There are several tricks to improve CSP performance like forward checking, building a DAG and then do a topological sort and so on...

Just let me know, if you need more information about CSP :)